# How to send json data to client side from express nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, client

I have an application, where I need to send the form data through XMLHttpRequest. When I send that information over, I then need to validate the form, then send information back to the client based on if the form validates or not. I'm using nodejs with express.

My client side code is:

```
editor.save().then((output) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  formData.append('name', document.getElementById('inputProductName').value);
  xhr.open('post', '/items/add', true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error: ' + error);
  return;
}).finally(() => {
  // This is where I need to retrieve the validation code and redirect accordingly.
  if (success == false) {
    window.location.href = '/items/add/failed';
  } else {
    window.location.href = '/items/add/success';
  }
});
```

My server side code is this:

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (fields.name.length < 1) { // If the name is empty
      res.status(200).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Product name must be specified'
      });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Product added successfully'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

So if the the validation fails, then I want to be able to get the success and message variable through the client end if possible.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you wrote?

Comment: My client console is giving an error saying success is not defined. I was originally just going to try to use flash messaging and res.redirect, but it wasn't working, which is why I'm redirecting on the client side.

Comment: Why would `success` be defined? It's a variable that you don't define anyway. And you're making a request with XHR but never looking at the response. (Why are you using xhr instead of fetch if you're working with promises anyway?)

Comment: I'm fairly new to javascript, when I googled about sending form data xhr was the first thing that showed up, so I went with it. Should I be looking at fetch instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [using `fetch` API from MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

- fetch data via `POST`
- `await` response
- based on `response.success` act accordingly

Additionally,looking a the server-side code, it doesn't appear necessary that `form encoding` be used.

- Suggest sending the data in json format and have the server check the request.body for the appropriate field to be populated.

pseudo code

```js
editor.save().then(async (output) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', document.getElementById('inputProductName').value);
    const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    // ... additional form data here, looks like you can send JSON, no need for form encoding
    }
    if(response.success) {
      window.location.href = '/items/add/success';
    } else {
      window.location.href = '/items/add/failed';
    }

}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error: ' + error);
  return;
})
```

Note that the anonymous function `() => {}` is now `async () => {}` to allow `await` on the `fetch` call.

- [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)